# What is this polynomial zero everywhere but $n!$ at point $n$?

Tags: polynomials, interpolation

For an integer $n \geq 2$, define a set of $n$ points $(p_{x,1},p_{y,1}),\ldots,(p_{x,n},p_{y,n})$ as follows. For $1 \leq i \leq n-1$, let $(p_{x,i},p_{y,i}) = (i,0)$, and $(p_{x,n},p_{y,n}) = (n,n!)$. Put differently, the first $n-1$ points evaluate to zero, and the last point to the factorial of $n$.

For any $n \geq 2$, take the interpolating polynomial $P_n$ through the point set defined above. For example, for $2 \leq n \leq 4$, we get:

- $P_2 = x$,
- $P_3 = -x+x^2$, and
- $P_4 = 2 x - 3 x^2 + x^3$.

I can keep going with the help of a computer easily, but how can you generalize this for any $n$? Is there some nice closed form (and how to find it)? This is probably easy, I just haven't worked with polynomials in a long time. Maybe this is even some known polynomial that has a name.

Comment: I must be misunderstanding the examples: shouldn't $P_2(1)$ be equal to $0$? (you make it equal to $1$). And $P_3$ as you give it it negative on every natural number..

Comment: @ClementC. It should be correct, so $P_2(0) = 0$, but $P_2(1) = 1! = 1$. But oops, there is a typo with $P_3$ (fixed now).

Comment: I guess then your second line should be shifted, shouldn't it? You currently have $P_n(i)=0$ for $1\leq i \leq n-1$, while you seem to want $P_n(i)=0$ for $0\leq i \leq n-2$ and $P_n(n-1)=n!$ (?).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way to write polynomials is as a product, not a sum.
For example, your $P_4=x(x-1)(x-2)$.  That way, it is clear that $P_4=0$ when $x=0,1,2$, and $P_4(3)=6=3!$.

Comment: Thank you, very clear and easy :-)